# How do you simplify a boolean algebra expression when it's a two by three expression?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm a little stuck in my simplifying of this boolean logic expression. If it was $2 \times 2$, I know I could foil, but I can't find any law that will help me go any further. Would someone help me figure out where to go now?

In this attempt, $\cdot$ stands for logical AND, $+$ for logical OR, and $\overline{A}$ stands for NOT A.

*Simplify: $\overline{(A+B)}\cdot\overline{(C+D+E)}+\overline{(A+B)}$*
\begin{align}
&\overline{(A+B)}\cdot\overline{(C+D+E)}+\overline{(A+B)}\\
\text{de Morgan's law}~~~&(\overline{A}\cdot\overline{B})\cdot(\overline{C}\cdot\overline{D}\cdot\overline{E})+\overline{(A+B)}\\
\text{de Morgan's law}~~~&(\overline{A}\cdot\overline{B})\cdot(\overline{C}\cdot\overline{D}\cdot\overline{E})+(\overline{A}\cdot \overline{B})
\end{align}

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDDB3.jpg) is an image of my attempt on paper.

Comment: Please use MathJax to write math correctly. Also, what operation is in between $\neg(A+B)$ and $\neg(C+D+E)$?

Comment: $U \wedge V \vee U = U$.

Comment: It's an and symbol. I'll look into MathJax now. Thank you.

Comment: When you refer to the expression been a 2 by 2, are you referring to it been solved on a Karnaugh map?

Comment: I mean 2 x 2 by saying another way of writing something like (A + B)(C + D).

Comment: Maybe I’m reading it wrong, but it looks to simplify to $\overline{A+B}$.

Comment: Why can’t you foil?  Rewrite $C+D+E$ as $C+(D+E)$ and apply your rule.

Comment: Michael Burr, you're right. I can do that according to associative law. But how can you already see the final simplified form?

Answer (score 1):

You can just follow Eric Towers' comment:
Take $U = \overline{A+B}$ and $V = \overline{C+D+E}$, and apply one of the absorption laws:
$$(U\cdot V)+U=U.$$
(The other would be $(U+V)\cdot U = U$.)
This was certainly what Michael Burr meant in his first comment.